# Eclipse Sirius custom layout

Tags: eclipse, emf, eclipse-gmf, eclipse-sirius

I am fairly new to Sirius developing environment, I am trying to develop a custom module layout using Sirius, the documentation available is a bit advanced.

Is there any good source or tutorial available that explains how to create custom layout that explains the basics.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a custom layout when pressing the "Arrange-All" button in the Sirius toolbar of your diagram [take a look at this article](https://www.eclipse.org/sirius/doc/developer/extensions-provide_custom-arrange-all.html). Didn't read it completely but looks quite good if that's what you need.

Comment: This is the only documentation available (the official i was referring to), and it is very unfriendly, and full of errors. and advanced, if you know any other documentation available  ?